# Updating from Ember 1.8.1 to Ember 1.9 with Ember Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm am currently updating an Ember app built with Ember Starter kit from Ember 1.8.1 to 1.9 and Handlebars 2.0. I’m trying to update successfully without having to refactor a lot of code - I’m hoping this is possible.

At the moment, I’m getting an error in the console which says ‘Error: Unknown template object: function’. From what I have read it is because I’m using a template compiler which only understands Handlebars 1.3. I’m currently using Gulp to compile my templates. I’ve moved from gulp-ember-templates to [gulp-handlebars](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars) which states that I can compile my templates using a specific Handlebars version.

This is how my 'templates' gulp task looks like:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.dev.templates + '**/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
        handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'TM.TEMPLATES',
        noRedeclare: true,
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'))
});
```

..and my package.json has

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "handlebars": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

I've read that I may need to update the runtime version, but I don't know where I can do this so I assumed if I installed the latest ember-template-compiler from NPM and referenced it in my gulpfile like below

```
//COMPILE ALL PULGIN FILES
gulp.task("all", function(){
    return gulp.src([
            paths.dev.vendor + "jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            paths.dev.vendor + "handlebars/handlebars.js",
            "/node_modules/ember-template-compiler/lib/main.js",
            paths.dev.vendor + "ember/ember.js", 
        ])
        .pipe(concat("all.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/js/"));  
});
```

...it would work.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting ‘Error: Unknown template object: function’. I understand I could try and migrate the app over to Ember CLI there is no capacity for this at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider migrating to [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/) first? It should be v0.1.15 for ember 1.8.1. Since ember app kit is deprecated a long time ago ember-cli will give you a much smoother upgrade path in future.

Comment: I did but as AMD is not the approach used in the Ember Starter Kit, I was hoping I could avoid having to refactor the code and get the update working as quickly as possible.

Comment: Honestly `1.8` is very, very old! Depending on your codebase you should first migrate to `ember-cli`, then to `1.13`, and then to `2.0`, and then to `2.18`, or you just start with a plain `2.18` and `ember-cli` project and migrate the app route by route with copy & paste. I would probably go the second way.